# Run my app from when connected to a particular wifi : ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, ios10

Many Wi-Fi hotspots these days have a "web login", especially free ones. You know, the ones that redirect any HTTP request to their login form.ios first connect to a  wifi network then opens up the login page of the network where we fill our credentials and then it let us access the internet. Now I am creating a ios app that runs when connected to a particular network and instead of opening my browser the app takes user credentials once and automatically login for user and user can access the internet. Now how do I open my app whenever the user connects to the network and instead of opening up the app I would like it to show my app notification with the option of Login or Logout in the notification bar.

In android it appears like this:

[image: Notification bar in android]

Comment: Try add broadcast receiver and listen network changes, when wi-fi connected run your app

Comment: Have you looked at the [Apple documentation for Captive Wi-Fi](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204497)?  I use the auto logon feature and it works well as long as the Captive Wi-Fi doesn't change the portal setup.

Comment: I think broadcast receiver is in android not in ios can you provide a sample for it.Any help would be appreciated!Thanks @AzmalTech

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MwcsMac I tried this but its not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a URL scheme within your app, and then configure your login page to call a certain URL containing the information you need. For example, if your app was called "Foobar", a valid URL might look like `foobar://auth?user=jacobking&pass=password123`. As I said, you will need to tell iOS that your app is listening for the `foobar` scheme. When iOS receives this URL, it will ask your app delegate if it can open it which you will answer through `canOpenURL`.

A detailed explaination and code examples can be found [here](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-deep-linking-in-swift/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not what I meant.First of all, i cannot modify the code of the website.I'm trying to automate the web login process to access the internet in my university where we have to enter credentials each and every time to access the internet.Secondly, I want my app to come in the notification centre with a login button whenever I connect to my university wifi SSID in notification centre.For further understanding I have updated my question please check it.